# What is the maximum length of a USSD response (not request length)?

Tags: c++, c, gsm, at-command, ussd

What is the maximum length of a USSD **response** (**not the length of a request**) from a modem ?
so I can define my response variable to that length.

```
#define Max_Response_Length ???
BYTE response[Max_Response_Length];
```

Thank you for your understanding.

**EDIT:** What are you people!
do you think I am that lazy or even retarded to not even do a **google** or **wikipedia** search, before I come here!
I spent hours trying to search for answers to my question, of the **USSD RESPONSE (NOT, NOT and NOT REQUEST) LENGTH**
and wikipedia does not specify if (182 characters) does include the response or not.

Comment: @4386427, that was really offensive. I know but I asked for the response length not the request length, and wikipedia does not specify.

Comment: Maybe not offensive, but rude for sure. I already flagged the comment earlier.

Comment: Requests and responses both are USSD messages. Since USSD messages are restricted to 160 bytes, that means both requests and responses are restricted to that. Makes sense: since they're all carried by the GSM signalling channels, like SMS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

USSD messages are up to 182 alphanumeric characters long.

Source:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data

Comment: I edited this answer so it's not just a link, but from the linked duplicate I understand that the number of raw bytes is 160, and then those can be interpreted as 182 7-bit characters.